# SQLAlchemy filtering using where only works with one column

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using SQL Alchemy to access an SQLite Database. However, I am facing some bizarre behaviour with the where() filter. The table is defined as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, MetaData, String, Table, select, Integer

metadata = MetaData()
self._table = Table(
    self._table_name,
    metadata,
    Column("email", String(64), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column("name", String(64), nullable=False),
    Column("password", String(64), nullable=False),
)
```

And I insert a row using:

```
query = self._table.insert().values(
            name=user.name, email=user.email, password=user.password
        )
session.execute(query)
session.commit()
```

Now, when I try to fetch the find the row using the following code, it returns an empty list:

```
query = select([self._table]).where(self._table.c.email == "toto@toto.com")
print("Compiled Query ", query)
data = self._execute_select(query)
print("Found Data: ", data)
```

The above code gives output:

```
Columns are:  ImmutableColumnCollection(user.name, user.email, user.password)
Compiled Query  SELECT "user".name, "user".email, "user".password
FROM "user"
WHERE "user".email = :email_1
Found Data:  []
```

If I change it slightly to use "name" instead of "email" it seems to work as expected:
(ONLY the second line has been changed!)

```
print("Columns are: ", self._table.c)
query = select([self._table]).where(self._table.c.name == "pawan")
print("Compiled Query ", query)
data = self._execute_select(query)
print("Found Data: ", data)
```

The output for the above code is:

```
Columns are:  ImmutableColumnCollection(user.email, user.name, user.password)
Compiled Query  SELECT "user".email, "user".name, "user".password
FROM "user"
WHERE "user".name = :name_1
Found Data:  [('tototo', 'pawan', 'toto@toto.com')]
```

No other operations are performed between these two lines so the data is definitely present in the DB the whole time. I noticed that changing the "name" to "password" and value to "tototo" does not find any data either. So essentially, I am ONLY able to search using "name".

Please help me understand this error.

Comment: There is a `username` column in the last example that isn't in the table definition - please make sure you are sharing the correct code.  It would also help if you provided sample data that will reliably reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Sorry. it's supposed to be "name". I have updated it now. Sample data that reliably reproduces the above behaviour is also provided as 
name = "pawan", 
password = "tototo", 
email= "toto@toto.com"

Comment: Works for me.  Perhaps `execute_select` is doing something?  Or there is an invisible character somewhere?  It's hard to be sure without a comprehensive [mre].

Comment: have you executed this query in the database shell ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you for your help. I actually found the error and it was extremely stupid of me....the email and password had been interchanged when entering into the DB. I found this while executing a test